# Define custom URL with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to define an URL with the following format:

> /config?customer=...&integration_type=...

where customer and integration_type are variables.

So far, as stated in the document. The user can define their URL as:

```
@app.route("/do_thing/<some_variable>")
def hello(some_variable):
   return "Hello World!"
```

The URL will have the format

> /do_thing/variable

But that is not what I want. How to define a format as I mentioned?

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve the problem yourself?  Do you have any code you could share so we can see what you've tried?

Comment: This isn't a question, just a statement.

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format that you want has query string in it. We don't define query string in format. You can just get the parameters value directly by this.

```
user = request.args.get('user')
@app.route("/do_thing")
def hello():
integration_type = request.args.get('integration_type')
customer = request.args.get('customer')
   return "Hello World!"
```